# send Windows Sandbox network traffic through host VPN connection

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, windows-sandbox

I want to run an application in a Windows Sandbox. The application must contact a server only accessible through the host Windows PC VPN connection. But Windows Sandbox network traffic only uses the host PC default Ethernet.

In other words, an HTTPS server that is only accessible from a host connected to a VPN. I'd like to test an application within a Windows Sandbox on my Windows laptop that is connected to the VPN. Unfortunately, applications inside the Windows Sandbox do not know how to contact that HTTPS Server over the VPN.  So how can I have all Windows Sandbox traffic route through the host Windows VPN Network Interface instead of the host Windows Ethernet Network Interface?

Comment: Windows Sandbox is known to have trouble establishing any sort of internet connection when the host PC is connected to a VPN. The easiest solution for you might be to install your VPN application *inside the Sandbox itself* so that the virtual machine routes all its own traffic through the tunnel, regardless of whether the host PC is on a VPN or not.